# Modifying NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I modify `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` on the fly, programmatically. My message depends on custom app language, not system language.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have write permission to `info.Plist` so you can not modify it dynamically. If you at all want to change language you can use localisation. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1823/_index.html) says

> If your app supports localization, be sure to localize CFBundleDisplayName by adding it to all your language-specific InfoPlist.strings files. Furthermore, be sure to use a name that complies with the App Review Guidelines for your app.

Same thing can apply for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`